# What happens when you cast an activity to an interface in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, interface, casting

I have the following interface:

```
interface ResultReceiver {
    fun getSerialNumber(): String
    fun getDevicePassword(): String
    fun getMacAddress(): String
    fun getDevice(): BluetoothDevice
}
```

Within my DialogFragment I am casting the attached Activity to my interface like so:

```
resultReceiver = requireActivity() as ResultReceiver
```

What happens when I perform this type cast?

Here is my activity code to give a little more context to my question:

```
class ScannerActivity: AppCompatActivity(), ResultReceiver {

    ...

    override fun getSerialNumber(): String {
        return serialNumber
    }

    override fun getDevicePassword(): String {
        return devicePassword
    }

    override fun getMacAddress(): String {
        return macAddress
    }

    override fun getDevice(): BluetoothDevice {
        return device
    }
}
```

I am trying to send some Strings to my fragment from my activity.

Comment: Your Activity is nothing but a class. Assume if you somehow could modify the AppCompatActivity and implement from this interface. In this case it will succeed. But in your example it will crash))

Comment: You can take for example something like this `result = String() as ResultReceiver` and there's no any difference between this and your question.

Comment: I think I understand. If I implement the interface in my activity, will it succeed?

Comment: Yeah, you can implement it in activity, but you need also to cast your `requireActivity` to activity in which your fragment exists. But what do you want to achieve? Maybe there's another way?

Comment: Do I need to cast to my activity if I know that the fragment is attached to the activity I want already? I am trying to send data from my activity to my fragment via interface. I will edit my question with my activity code.

Comment: I see. If you want to communicate between activity-fragment, your activity must implement that interface. And your fragments needs a method to get that interface as a parameter. I can attach a video where you can find the implementation, you'll understand it more clear than I will explain)) https://youtu.be/p2mXSHgNUgs

Comment: BTW you can furthermore investigate other topics like `SharedViewModel` and `FragmentResultAPI` which are more recommended ways for communicating activity-fragment and fragment-fragment. Link - https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate

Answer (score 2):

All the activities are classes which by the end extend from `Object`. In Kotlin it's `Any` but after compilation it will be `Object` again. So you can take any class and try to cast it to your interface. If that class will not have any relation (parent-child) with that interface, it will throw `ClassCastException`.